# How can I get Python argparse parameters for a module as a string?

Tags: python-2.7, command-line-interface, argparse

I have a module that I'm writing an ipython notebook to document. I'd like to have part of that documentation be the response to calling the module from the command line with the `--help` flag - the parameters set up using `argparse`. Is there a simple way of getting that as a formatted string?

Answer (score 2):

Call [`format_help()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.format_help) on your `ArgumentParser` instance.  It will give you a string with the help text.

Answer (score 0):

So what worked in the end is simply using `subprocess.check_output` as follows:

```
response = subprocess.check_output('python -m myscript -h')   
print response
```